# Assigning a default value to a MVC3 @HtmlDropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following code for a user profile prefix:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserProfile.Profile.Prefix.ID, Model.PrefixList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.Value.ToString()}).ToList() })
```

This works great if the person has a prefix in their name.  However, not everybody does.

The database brings in the selected prefix through an IEnumerable list like this:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
    {
        public User UserProfile { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<USStates> States { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Campus> CampusLocations { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Prefix> PrefixList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Suffix> SuffixList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatusList { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I set a default value without destroying the functionality of the preselected list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an overload : `SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, Object)`.

In your case, that would be:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserProfile.Profile.Prefix.ID, Model.PrefixList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.Value.ToString()}).ToList(), "-default value-" })`

Answer (score 0):

i think you bind your dropdown list like this it's below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Name"), "-Select Country-", new { @id = "ddlcountry" })
```

i think this will help you..

Comment: but which type of default value you wont  to set

Comment: @CKallemeres - I don't understand.  You want to override the selection that's already selected?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) overload:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue);
```

The last parameter is selected value. You could rewrite your method similar to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserProfile.Profile.Prefix.ID, Model.PrefixList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.Value.ToString()}).ToList(), "--- Default Value---" })
```

Hope this bill be of help to you.